# How to add to the extensions for an existing type in Ruby's MIME::Types

Tags: ruby, mime-types

`MIME::Types` recognises `txt` as `text/plain`

```
require 'mime/types'
MIME::Types.type_for("txt").first.to_s  # => "text/plain"
```

I want it to do the same thing for `tab`, which it doesn't by default

```
MIME::Types.type_for("tab").first.to_s  # => ""
```

So given that:

```
MIME::Types['text/plain'].first.extensions
```

is `["txt", "asc", "c", "cc", "h", "hh", "cpp", "hpp", "dat", "hlp"]`, why doesn't the following work:

```
MIME::Types['text/plain'].first.extensions.push("tab")
MIME::Types.type_for("tab").first.to_s  # => still just ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mime::Type` doesn't appear to have any methods for adding extensions to an existing registered handler. What you can do is convert an existing handler to a hash, add in your own extension, then re-register the handler. This will output a warning, but it will work:

```
text_plain = MIME::Types['text/plain'].first.to_hash
text_plain['Extensions'].push('tab')
MIME::Types.add(MIME::Type.from_hash(text_plain))
MIME::Types.type_for("tab").first.to_s # => 'text/plain'
```

Or if you want to be clever and confusing and do it all in one line:

```
MIME::Types.add(MIME::Type.from_hash(MIME::Types['text/plain'].first.to_hash.tap{ |text_plain| text_plain['Extensions'].push('tab') }))
MIME::Types.type_for("tab").first.to_s # => 'text/plain'
```

If for some reason you need to suppress the warning message, you can do it like this (assuming you are running the code on a linux-y system):

```
orig_stdout = $stdout
$stdout = File.new('/dev/null', 'w')
# insert the code block from above
$stdout = orig_stdout
```

Comment: That works perfectly, but not sure why convert it to hash...
This works too:
text_plain = MIME::Types['text/plain'].first
text_plain.extensions << 'tab'
MIME::Types.add(text_plain)

Comment: @iwiznia, at the time I wrote the question, that wasn't possible (see the history in https://github.com/halostatue/mime-types/blob/master/History.rdoc -- you can see that that hash-free method was not introduced until 2013-10-27, nearly 2 years after I wrote this post). But the hash method works in both the old and new versions, so I'm leaving my answer as-is for highest compatibility. Thanks for your note though.

Answer (score 1):

another way is to creating a new content type, e.g

`stl_mime_type_hash = MIME::Type.new('application/vnd.ms-pkistl').to_hash
stl_mime_type_hash['Extensions'].push('stl')
MIME::Types.add(MIME::Type.from_hash(stl_mime_type_hash))`